# Genexus: Error CS0234 calling External Object with stored procedure in Gx Ev 3 U5

Tags: object, external, procedure, genexus

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure in Genexus X Evolution 3 Upgrade 5 and it doesn't generate the C# External Object code, so it gives me an error:

> error CS0234: El tipo o el nombre del espacio de nombres 'SdtdynQuery' no existe en el espacio de nombres 'GeneXus.Programs' (¨falta una referencia de ensamblado?)

How can I solve this?

Comment: If you want to post your question in Spanish, you may do so on http://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: For your information, I'm calling the External Ovject in a rule, if I call it from an event it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Ariel,

You could wrap the External Object Code inside a Procedure and use it that way from Transaction Rules.

Comment: Yes. Thats the easy workarround, buut I'd like to know if there is a solution for this? Thanks a lot!